# Binding problem about custom WPF LedControl with customizable ColorWhenOn and ColorWhenOff properties

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

This is what I need: a LedControl class, that paints a gradient circle according to its "IsOn" property. It has "ColorWhenOn" and "ColorWhenOff" customizable properties, that indicate how the circle should appear according to the led state. I need these colors to be defined in XAML for each LedControl, for example:

<myns:LedControl ColorWhenOn="Aqua" ColorWhenOff="Black" />

I've been struggling with this for some days, I even asked ChatGPT, but I still cannot figure it out. I tried many techniques, but none did work as needed. I prefer not to make it a subclass of CheckBox, because I want the "IsOn" property instead of "IsChecked" property.

I have a WPF library project containing LedControl.cs and Generic.xaml, and a WPF TestProject for using the LedControl in a Window.

The LedControl.cs class:

```
public class LedControl5 : Control, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        static LedControl5()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(LedControl5), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(LedControl5)));
        }

    //I'm trying to store the colors in RadiantGradientBrush objects
        private RadialGradientBrush currentBrushWhenOn = new RadialGradientBrush
        {
            Center = new Point(0.5, 0.5),
            GradientOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5),
            RadiusX = 0.5,
            RadiusY = 0.5,
            GradientStops = new GradientStopCollection
            {
                new GradientStop(Colors.LimeGreen, 0),
                new GradientStop(Colors.DarkGreen, 1),
            }
        };
        public RadialGradientBrush CurrentBrushWhenOn
        {
            get => currentBrushWhenOn;
            set => currentBrushWhenOn = value;
        }

        private RadialGradientBrush currentBrushWhenOff = new RadialGradientBrush
        {
            Center = new Point(0.5, 0.5),
            GradientOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5),
            RadiusX = 0.5,
            RadiusY = 0.5,
            GradientStops = new GradientStopCollection
            {
                new GradientStop(Colors.Gray, 0),
                new GradientStop(Colors.DimGray, 1),
            }
        };
        public RadialGradientBrush CurrentBrushWhenOff
        {
            get => currentBrushWhenOff;
            set => currentBrushWhenOff = value;
        }

        public Color ColorWhenOn
        {
            get => (Color)GetValue(PROPERTY_COLOR_WHEN_ON);
            set
            {
                SetValue(PROPERTY_COLOR_WHEN_ON, value);
                currentBrushWhenOn.GradientStops[0].Color = value;
                //currentBrushWhenOn.GradientStops[1].Color = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(ColorWhenOn));
                NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(CurrentBrushWhenOn));
            }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty PROPERTY_COLOR_WHEN_ON =
            DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(ColorWhenOn), typeof(Color), typeof(LedControl5), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Colors.Pink)); //default colors are ignored...

        public Color ColorWhenOff
        {
            get => (Color)GetValue(PROPERTY_COLOR_WHEN_OFF);
            set
            {
                SetValue(PROPERTY_COLOR_WHEN_OFF, value);
                currentBrushWhenOff.GradientStops[0].Color = value;
                //currentBrushWhenOff.GradientStops[1].Color = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(ColorWhenOff));
                NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(currentBrushWhenOff));
            }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty PROPERTY_COLOR_WHEN_OFF =
            DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(ColorWhenOff), typeof(Color), typeof(LedControl5), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Colors.Yellow));
        
        public bool IsOn
        {
            get => (bool)GetValue(PROPERTY_IS_ON);
            set
            {
                SetValue(PROPERTY_IS_ON, value);
                NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(IsOn));
                if (value)
                    NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(currentBrushWhenOn));
                else
                    NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(currentBrushWhenOff));
            }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty PROPERTY_IS_ON =
            DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(IsOn), typeof(bool), typeof(LedControl5), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false));

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
            => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

The content of "Generic.xaml" file in "Converters" folder of "MyUtils.GUI" project:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyUtils.GUI">
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:LedControl5}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:LedControl5}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Ellipse x:Name="mainEllipse" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsOn" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="mainEllipse" Property="Fill" Value="{Binding CurrentBrushWhenOn, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsOn" Value="False">
                            <Setter TargetName="mainEllipse" Property="Fill" Value="{Binding CurrentBrushWhenOff, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

My window code (project "TestProject"), I've put a checkBox that's bound to the LedControl:

```
<Window x:Class="TestProject.Window2"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:mynamespace="clr-namespace:MyUtils.GUI;assembly=MyUtils.GUI"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Window2" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <CheckBox x:Name="chk" Content="Toggle" />
            <mynamespace:LedControl5 Height="35" x:Name="lc" IsOn="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=chk}" ColorWhenOn="Aqua" ColorWhenOff="Black" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

When I click the checkBox it works, but it shows just the Green/Gray colors when On/Off. How to make it use the defined ColorWhenOn (Aqua) and ColorWhenOff (Black) colors when checking/unchecking?

Comment: There must not be any other code than SetValue in the setter of a dependency property like ColorWhenOn and ColorWhenOff. In order to react on changes of the property value, you must register a PropertyChangedCallback.

Comment: Also be aware that a class derived from DepedencyObject does not need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged. Dependency properties already provide their own change notification mechanism.